# Node.js MySQL Connection Error. ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have 2 servers, one running the frontend code (Node.js, express) and the other running MySQL with PHPMyAdmin, both are working standalone and I can confirm the MySQL database is running on 3306 but whenever I try to connect via Node.js (code below) I get a connection refused error.

```
    const conn = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '192.168.1.250',
        user: 'mcd',
        password: '**********',
        database: 'mcd'
    })

    conn.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
```

The IP address I have used for the host is the IP address of the MySQL server. So unsure why it cannot connect since it is running on the default port.

Comment: copy error message here, this will help to identify the problem

Comment: A) Server isn't running even though you think it is. B) Server isn't listening on the correct IP, it's bound to `127.0.0.1` only. C) Your firewall isn't permissive enough.

Comment: Apologies, here is the error ```errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.1.250',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my connection to Node.js:

```
pool = mysql.createPool({host:"localhost"
                        ,port:"3306"
                    ,database:"db_name"
                        ,user:"user_name"
                    ,password:"password_for_user"
                    ,timezone:"utc"
          ,multipleStatements:true
                         ,max:1000
                         ,min:1
           ,idleTimeoutMillis:defs.QUERY_TIMEOUT});  
 if ( pool && pool.getConnection ) {  
   pool.getConnection(function(errsts, conn) {
    var resp = {};

    if ( errsts ) {
      resp['error'] = errsts;
      return;        
    }
    resp['state'] = "connected";
        
    if ( cbRoutine ) {        
      cbRoutine(conn, resp, objParams);
        
      if ( conn != undefined ) {
        conn.release();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

localhost is correct for my usage, you should replace its your name or IP address.
defs.QUERY_TIMEOUT is defined in my source as:

```
var QUERY_TIMEOUT         = 10 * 1000;
```

In my code **cbRoutine** is a call back function passed in as a parameter to call on successful connection.

Answer (score -1):

The `ECONNREFUSED` error indicates that it can't connect to where the function is hosted (in this case localhost)

*dbConnection.js*

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10, // default = 10
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'dname'
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: Not sure why but I used to connect to 'localhost' but that stopped working somehow. So now I connect to 127.0.0.1 and it works fine.